# Use CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH to link a library outside build tree

Tags: macos, cmake, rpath

This issue is MacOS X specific. I would like to link a library `lib_xxx` that sits outside my build tree at some arbitrary location. It will be at the same location in all systems. By default CMake would add the dependency as follows

```
@executable_path/libwupienginemac.dylib
```

I would like to know how to change `@executable_path` to either:

1. Absolute path to the library. I see, for example the following in `otool` output

   ```
   /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.0.0)
   ```
2. `@rpath` I could then manage the location of `lib_xxx` using `RPATH`. I prefer this option.

From the documentation and forums it looks like `CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH` should solve the issue and implement option (2). Yet the `CMakeLists.txt` below still results in `@executable_path/libwupienginemac.dylib` dependency.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(xxx_test)

set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 1)
find_library(LIB_XXX lib_xxx
    PATHS "/path/to/lib_xxx/lib"
    )
if (NOT LIB_XXX)
    message(FATAL_ERROR ""LIB XXX not found")
 endif()

add_executable(xxx_test xxx_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(xxx_test
    ${LIB_XXX}
)
# Try running the executable at once
add_custom_target(wibut_test_run ALL
    COMMAND xxx_test
    DEPENDS xxx_test
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at present CMake doesn't have any mechanisms to deal with this issue. I ended up copying my external dependency to ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}, which works fine for my scenarios.

Another way to handle this would be to use install_name_tool -id